# Android Studio - unit testing with library project: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I am using the [VM unit testing](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) of the Android gradle plugin and all my unit tests run fine from within Android Studio and via gradle command line invocation.

But when I run a test in Android Studio on a class that has a dependency to a library project included with `compile project (":library:myLib")` I get a ClassNotFoundException on the class from the library project. However the test runs fine when running gradle from the command line.

I am using junit 4 and powermock with mockito. No Robolectric or other frameworks.
I have set the test artifact to Unit Tests. As said, unit tests for classes that have no dependency to a library project work fine in my setup.

Any ideas?